# Problema con Alert fade in (bootstrap), solo se muestra una vez

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap, bootstrap-3

estoy tratando realizar un alerta con bootstrap. se visualiza de manera correcta cuando se recibe la respuesta correctamente, o algun error. pero cuando realizo otra accion que involucra otra respuesta ajax, este ya no me muestra el alert.

Aqui esta mi index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Inicio</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>
<!-- zqui dibujo el alert -->
<div id="alertDiv"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

en mi archivo javascript.

```
$.ajax({
          url: "ToAjax.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: fd,
          contentType: false,
          processData:false,
          success: function(data){

            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(json);
               $('#frmNewProduct').trigger('reset');
               $('#modalProduct').modal('toggle');

         // aqui dibujo el alert      
               $('#alertDiv').append(
                '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>'
               )
              .addClass("alert alert-success fade in")
              .append('<strong>' + json.message + '!</strong> Your message has been sent successfully.');


          },
          error: function(data){
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
               $('#modalProduct').modal('toggle');

          }
        });



    });


    };
```

Cabe mencionar que los datos los ingreso desde un modal. y al hacer el registro exitoso, se cierra este.

pero el alert solo se dibuja una vez. tengo que refrescar la pagina para cuando haga otro insert este dibuje el alert. las peticiones son exitosas, entonces mi problema es en front end. tal vez la forma en que lo estoy dibujando. no se si es la correcta. alguien que me oriente.
Saludos!

Comment: Intenta con `modal('show')`

Comment: @alanfcm es un alert, no un modal. el modal lo utilizo para guardar los datos. el modal no es el problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que `data-dismiss` elimina el `alertDiv`.  Para lograr lo que quieres, debes de manejar lo que hace el button y cambiar a `data-hide` asi:

```js
function showAlert() {
         // aqui dibujo el alert      
               $('#alertDiv').html("").append(
                '<a href="#" class="close" data-hide="alert">&times;</a>'
               )
              .addClass("alert alert-success fade in")
              .append('<strong> json.message !</strong> Your message has been sent successfully.').show();
              $("[data-hide]").on("click", function(){
        $(this).closest("." + $(this).attr("data-hide")).hide();
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Inicio</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- zqui dibujo el alert -->
<div id="alertDiv"></div>
<button onclick="showAlert()">show</button>

</body>
</html>
```